# Full touch access despite TalkBack/screen reader

Tags: android, talkback

**Preamble**

TalkBack is an Accessibility Service for Android that helps blind and vision-impaired users interact with their devices. It’s an screen reader, that reads every user interface element.

This is great visually impaired people can use so many different apps that have not specially adapted.
But it does not work for all types of apps. I want to use a widget, that handle all touch events despite TalkBack is active.

VoiceOver is the complement of TalkBack in IOS. Here is the solution for my problem in IOS.
[VoiceOver accessibility in a virtual musical instrument iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886669/voiceover-accessibility-in-a-virtual-musical-instrument-iphone-app)

**Question**

I implemented this solution to my IOS App and it works fine. **Is there any equivalent for Android/TalkBack?**

> [ mySubView setAccessibilityTraits: UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction ];

Apps that play sound directly by touch should be able to use with TalkBack on. Instrument apps, several games and apps like mine, that make a room discoverable with 3D Sound, should work with TalkBack on.
Turning off TalkBack is for a blind person **not** an option. It’s like turning of the screen for seeing people.

If you think there should be such a function, please upvote.